# HTML Anchors in a formula field

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, page-layout

On the standard case layout, I have replaced the Case Comment related list with a visualforce page. because of that, the link to the case comment related no longer appears.

Is it possible to create a formula field which will have an HTML anchor that will navigate the user to a specific section on the page once he clicks on it, something like this?

```
<a href="/5001r00001vBtRN#5001r00001vBtRN_RelatedEmailMessageList_target">Email List</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`HYPERLINK()` function](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5):

HYPERLINK( *url* , *friendlyName* *[, target]* )

Where url is `"/5001r00001vBtRN#5001r00001vBtRN_RelatedEmailMessageList_target"`, friendlyName would be `"Email List"`, and target is your opportunity to open this in a new tab/window if desired.

### Usage:

You would want to create a formula field of type `Text` and enter this function:

```
HYPERLINK("/5001r00001vBtRN#5001r00001vBtRN_RelatedEmailMessageList_target", "Email List")
```

You can then merge the value of this field onto your visualforce page.